# UIdocumentPickerViewController doesn't pick PDF's from the simulator

Tags: swift, uidocumentpickerviewcontroller

Here is the code that presents the picker when clicked on a button. I've tried the same on a different mac device and it worked just fine. Not sure what's different. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

```swift
var controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController!
        if fromPDF {
            controller = UIDocumentPickerViewController(documentTypes: ["com.adobe.pdf"], in: .import)
        } else {
            controller = UIDocumentPickerViewController(documentTypes: ["public.data", "public.content", "public.text", "public.image"], in: .import)
        }
        controller.delegate = self
        present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

[This is what I see when the picker is presented](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g8Yuw.png)

Comment: Version of mac os on each mac?  Version of xcode on each mac?

Comment: Not related to your question but why not simply `let controller = UIDocumentPickerViewController(documentTypes: fromPDF ?  ["com.adobe.pdf"]:["public.data", "public.content", "public.text", "public.image"], in: .import)`

Comment: @LeoDabus yeah that works too :)

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve Version on the working one: macOS Monterey 12.0.1, Xcode version - 13.2.1. Versions the other one: macOS Monterey 12.0.1, Xcode version - 13.3.1